# Web scraping through web pages using JSoup

Tags: java, web, screen-scraping, jsoup

Ive made a web scraper to scraper pieces of information on the IMDB. It traversed each page by changing the number in the url to a different random one and then repeated the web scraping process on this new page.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/  <--Changing this number for a new movie.

How can I do this on the BFI website? I cant see a way to go from film to film.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following randomly generated links is not the most efficient way to traversed over WWW...
You really should follow URL's that you found on other pages. You can use [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) that seems to be easiest Java crawler to start with. There are also [some alternatives](http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was hoping i could go to a page and there would be a link for next movie or something of the sort which i could use to traverse the movies but there arent any Urls that i can follow. Using a crawler will I be able to just go through the pages of one website?

Comment: Sure. There is shouldVisit method where you can specify if you want to parse a page. https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/BasicCrawler.java